# Kendo "ToDataSourceResult" method won't create pagination while querying a SQL Server view

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, ef-database-first

I have a project written with ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server as the database, Entity Framework (database first) as the ORM, and Kendo UI.

I figured out the issue occurs when performing a query on a view, the pagination won't appear in the final result. The profiler result proves it, which is shared below.

For this test I made two different queries. The first one is on a table and the second one is on my view, and the results are totally different.

I'm using the `ToDataSourceResult` method from Kendo (`Kendo.Mvc.Extensions` namespace), which is an extension method and will apply to an `IQueryable` of any type.

First scenario (with table):

```
SomeDb.Table1.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(dataSourceRequest);
```

The profiler result for the table:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Column1] AS [Column1], 
    [Extent1].[Column2] AS [Column2], 
    [Extent1].[Column3] AS [Column3]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY 
    [Extent1].[Column1] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Second scenario (with SQL Server view):

```
SomeDb.View1.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(dataSourceRequest);
```

The profiler result for the view:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM (SELECT 
[Vw_View1].[Colum1] AS [Colum1], 
[Vw_View1].[Column2] AS [Colum2], 
[Vw_View1].[Colum3] AS [Colum3], 
[Vw_View1].[Colum4] AS [Colum4], 
[Vw_View1].[Colum5] AS [Colum5], 
[Vw_View1].[Colum6] AS [Colum6], 
[Vw_View1].[Colum7] AS [Colum7]
FROM [dbo].[Vw_View1] AS [Vw_View1]) AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]'
```

If more information is needed to solve this issue, let me know to add it here.

Thanks.